# Hashmap remove function returns null even thou the key is present in it

Tags: java, hashmap

This code should put all available space on a window into a hashmap with string keys. Then all spaces that are occupied by the snake should be removed from the hashmap, but the remove function returns null. When spring out the hashmap the exact snake's position keys are presenting it. What is the problem here?

```
HashMap<String, Integer> cells = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i <= WINDOW_WIDTH - UNIT_SIZE; i += UNIT_SIZE) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= WINDOW_HEIGHT - UNIT_SIZE; j += UNIT_SIZE)
        cells.put(i + " " + j, 1);

    }
    System.out.println("map"+cells);
    for (Rectangle s : snake){
        System.out.println((int)s.getX() + " " + (int)s.getY());
        System.out.println(cells.remove(s.getX() + "-" + s.getY()));
    }
```

Here is the console output

```
map{0 0=1, 80 160=1, 80 120=1, 0 160=1, 80 200=1, 80 80=1, 0 120=1, 80 40=1, 160 120=1, 80 0=1, 200 120=1, 40 40=1, 40 0=1, 200 0=1, 120 200=1, 160 200=1, 200 200=1, 160 160=1, 40 200=1, 160 80=1, 40 120=1, 200 40=1, 40 160=1, 120 120=1, 200 80=1, 120 160=1, 200 160=1, 40 80=1, 160 0=1, 0 200=1, 120 0=1, 120 40=1, 0 40=1, 120 80=1, 160 40=1, 0 80=1}
0 0
null
0 40
null
0 80
null
0 120
null
```

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that a 2D array would probably be a better choice to represent a 2D plane, you're putting a space between X and Y on insert and trying to retrieve a key with a dash instead of a space between them.

Comment: " " != "-". If you are misusing Strings to represent a pair of ints, you should at least put the knowledge how to build a key in a helper method.

Comment: Also, but that's probably a copy-paste problem, you forgot to close the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are casting `s.getX()` and `s.getY()` to `int` suggests that they are not `int`. So the keys you are trying to remove are not actually in the `Map`.

In order to remove the correct keys, you should also cast `s.getX()` and `s.getY()` to `int` in the call to `remove()`.

Oh, and also change the "-" to " ", in order for the keys to match.

```
System.out.println(cells.remove((int)s.getX() + " " + (int)s.getY()));
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't notice that